# Streaming API. How to resolve circular notification dependency

Tags: streaming-api, data-synchronization

I have two different systems (salesforce (SF) and private one (PO)). They must be synchronized. To provide near real time synchronization on salesforce part we are using [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) (similar approach is used on PO system).

In case PO get changes and sends data to SF (to make SF synchronized), after changes on SF part we are getting changes from SF via Streaming API (because SF was changed).

### So question is:

How to detect on SF part where from data was populated\changed and how to stop publishing changes into topic in case of changes from PO system to break circular changes?